# Android responsive desing

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design

Need to do responsive design this part of the activity, but have many problems.

Firstly, can´t put `@+id/bookstore_layoutTop` Layout with `match_parent` value, because top parent `relativelayout` expands it until the end of activity. This question entail more problems to align title and address texts.

This is my xml structure now.

How can I do it? Some idea? Thank you in advance.

[image: To do]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bookstore_bk_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookstore_tab_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bookstore_tab_top" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bookstore_layoutTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bookstore_imgLogo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bookstore_layoutTop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingTop="32dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bookstore_txtName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="NOMBRE DE LIBRERIA" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bookstore_txtAddress"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25sp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                            android:text="Dirección de librería muuuuuu muuuuuuuuy larga."
                            android:textSize="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the picture you show the desired result?

Comment: Yes Klaus66, the picture is desired result, no actual result in displays.

Comment: OK, let me work it out. I think the layout you prepared can be simplified

Comment: Ok Klauss66, I am working too and trying to do with static height in top parent RelativeLayout structure. I dislike this option instead of real responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with (I left the background black, since I didn't have the other pictures to complete the decoration):

[image]

This picture is relative to a 320*480 @ 160dpi (mdpi) display (for better 
transfer speed).

Anyway, it scales well from ldpi up to hdpi (for higher resolutions, you better 
prepare higher resolution graphics)

Please note that the image has been reduced to **480*128 @ 240 dpi** and put in 
**res/drawable-hdpi**:

I also prepared the "home icon" and the bookstore logo as 240 dpi pictures in 
the same folder

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bookstore_bk_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bookstore_tab_top"
        />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                android:layout_width="58dp"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bookstore_logo"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookstore_txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="NOMBRE DE LIBRERIA"
                android:textColor="#f9daac"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="2"
                android:shadowDy="2"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bookstore_bk_top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spacer_left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookstore_txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bookstore_home"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="C/Arzobispo Morcillo N°27\n50020 Zaragoza"
            android:textSize="10dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helped. In case, accepting my answer and upvoting would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Thank for your answer Klaus66, I am learning your solution to compare with my actual structure and reconsider it to do better.

Comment: Or worse! ;) Anyway, I tricked my onCreate to remove the TitleBar and make the app FullScreen (that is, removing the StatusBar Too). I assume you already have that code handy - or I can give it tou you.